# is there any android library for pie chart which will support custom font in the slice of the pie chart?

Tags: android, pie-chart, custom-font

**android pie chart with bangla font**

[image]

I have used this in gradle. I don't know how to use custom font 
please any one can help me

implementation `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3`

Answer (score 1):

You can set TypeFace like this:

```
PieData data = new PieData(yourDataSet);
data.setValueTypeface(typeFaceObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

check [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java)

Try setValueTypeface(Typeface tf); method

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use your font intead of this "fonts/opensans_regular.ttf"

```
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/opensans_regular.ttf");
dataSet.setValueTypeface( font );
    PieData data = new PieData( dataSet );
    data.setValueTypeface( font );
```